# Model View Controller in Android

Tags: android

I write android project that use MVC concept , and load  available data from the model to controller to pass it to view to display it .But is there any way to load data not available and when you ensure this data is available to controller to pass it to View class to display it?.

Comment: That depends on details of Model implementation. Does it allows for registering `DataSetObserver` objects and notify them of any changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observer Pattern is the answer. You will need a mechanism that Controller will register himself for Load Data Event. Which basically triggered by an Observable Class which tells observer that something has changed. And whenever this event will occur Controller will go and get the data from Modal and forward it to View.